# Spring JDBC query BETWEEN DATE from HSQLDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, hsqldb, spring-jdbc

I'm trying to query data from **HSQLDB 2.2.8** with **Spring JDBC 3.1.2.RELEASE**, here's the statement:

```
"SELECT id, account_id, operator_id, amount, currency_type, date
    FROM account_entries WHERE account_id=? AND date BETWEEN DATE '?' AND DATE '?' + 1 DAY"
```

Properties are:

```
1 (java.lang.Integer)
2012-09-06 (java.sql.Date)
2012-09-06 (java.sql.Date)
```

The error I receive:

```
PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT id, account_id, operator_id, amount,
currency_type, date FROM account_entries WHERE account_id=?
AND date BETWEEN DATE '?' AND DATE '?' + 1 DAY]; data exception:
invalid datetime format; nested exception is java.sql.SQLDataException:
data exception: invalid datetime format
```

Comment: why quotes around the placeholders for dates, is that needed?

Comment: @Vikdor: Without them I get another exception: "PreparedStatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [...]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unexpected token: ? required: AND"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must either drop the date casts:

`... date BETWEEN ? AND ? + 1 DAY ...`

or keep them, but pass the parameters as correctly formatted strings (YYYY-MM-DD) instead of java.sql.Date objects.

Comment: Hell, yeah! The problem was with date casts.